# Проблемы кроссплатформенности или какая есть альтернатива QtConcurrent::run?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

Нужно запустить асинхронно функцию в отдельном потоке, я использовал `QtConcurrent::run` все было отлично когда я тестировал windows, но стоило мне запустить тот же код на linux, как он стал работать синхронно.

Тестируемый код:

```
void myRunFunction(QString name)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        qDebug() << name << " " << i << "from" << QThread::currentThread();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFuture<void> t1 = QtConcurrent::run(myRunFunction, QString("A"));
    QFuture<void> t2 = QtConcurrent::run(myRunFunction, QString("B"));
    QFuture<void> t3 = QtConcurrent::run(myRunFunction, QString("C"));

    t1.waitForFinished();
    t2.waitForFinished();
    t3.waitForFinished();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Подскажите как это исправить, ну или что можно еще попробовать?

Есть еще непонятка с  `QtConcurrent::run` при вызове функций класса.
На clang выдает следующее: `no matching function for call to 'run'`.
Поменял компилятор на mingw и ошибка изменилась на `reference to non-static member function must be called`

Тестовый код:

```
void A(int a)
{
    qDebug() << a;
}

class my_class : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    my_class(){}
    void B(int a)
    {
        qDebug() << a;
    }
    void call()
    {
        QtConcurrent::run(B, 5);// не работает
        QtConcurrent::run(A, 5);// работает
    }

};
```

Qt 4.8

[Англоязычная версия вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117725/cross-platform-issues-or-what-is-the-alternative-to-qtconcurrent-run)

Comment: Как именно вы определили, что код "стал работать синхронно"? Что значит "иногда" есть проблема с функциями класса? А иногда нет?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы путаете асинхронность и параллельность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QtConcurrent::run` использует `QThreadPool` по умолчанию, который сам определяет, сколько именно потоков делать. Для этого он использует системные функции, это же значение доступно через `QThread::idealThreadCount()`. Есть некая гарантия, что это значение будет как минимум равно 1.

Что делать? создать пул самому. Где то так

```
pool = new QThreadPool(this); 
pool->setMaxThreadCount(36); // нам нужно будет 36 потоков, у нас АМД, мы его проверяем
// а тут просто ещё один параметр, и все как обычно
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&pool, myRunFunction, QString("A"));
```

> Иногда есть проблема вызова QtConcurrent::run с функциями класса, выдает следующее: no matching function for call to 'run'

надо смотреть код. Но есть подозрение, что это не ошибки компиляции, а ошибки "подсказок кода". У QtCreator это слабое место - не с того не с сего может решить, что в коде ошибка и разукрасить весь код красными сообщениями.

Comment: правильно, что не работает. Функция A - это просто функция, а B - это функция-член класса. ей нужен ещё один параметр this. Если я не ошибаюсь, то нужно где то так `QtConcurrent::run(this, B, 5);` или даже так `QtConcurrent::run(this, &my_class::B, 5);`

Comment: Действительно, а я пробовал так `QtConcurrent::run(&my_class::B, 5)` и так 
`QtConcurrent::run(this->B , 5)`. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Вы всегда можете поставить галочку у ответа:)

Comment: Да да, помню) я еще проверяю))

Comment: А вы случаем не знаете как это сделать для qt 4.8? Просто QtConcurrent::run(QThreadPool *pool, Function function, ...) появился намного позже :с

Comment: скорее всего нужно через `QThreadPool::globalInstance()` получить дефолтный тредпул, а дальше можно менять свойства как я написал выше